# Python: Pipeline use some result of first classifier to second classifier (sklearn)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, text-classification

I want to use GaussianNB to classify into category A / B then use MultiNomialNB to classify only type A into sub-categories a1/ a2/ a3

**My question is how can I insert another first classifier into pipeline and use
only A result to be input of second classifier?**

what I have now:

```
pipeline1 = Pipeline([
('bow', CountVectorizer(analyzer=preprocess)), 
('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),  
('classifier', MultinomialNB()),])

scores = cross_val_score(pipeline1,train_X,train_Y,cv=cv,scoring=scorer)

pipeline1.fit(train_X,train_Y)
predictions= pipeline1.predict(test_X)
print (classification_report(predictions,test_Y))
```

example of my mock-dataset

[image]

Comment: Wrap the first classifier into a transformer that filters out only the A results to pass onto next.

Comment: Sorry, I don't clearly understand. You mean I have to create custom transfomer that do classify then filter, right? Do I need to use scikit-learn’s FeatureUnion to combine it with my pipeline? Or Could you please show me or put an example link about this? Thank You

Comment: Please first show the complete use case you want in detail. Current code you have shown dont show what you want to do.

Comment: I want to do text-classification into 3 classes (a1,a2,a3) and I want to get rid of data that do not fall into those 3 classes first. I have only 1 feature (text-content). So this is really my entire code. I havn't add my first classifier yet because I dont know how to add more to the pipeline.

Comment: But since you are doing a classification on 3 classes, all of the data will belong to those 3 classes. What will you remove?

Comment: There might be data that don't fall into those 3 classes. Because I labeled  it a1,a2,a3,None. And I want to remove 'None' data.

Comment: You want to add that classifier before MultiNomialNB. That can be done. Then what will be the input labels for multinomialNB? Please show the sample of data, targets for first classifier and target of second classifier (multinomialNB) for the same data.

Comment: (i edit my post for example of dataset) i guess what i'm doing now is impossible because I couldn't separate target in 1 pipeline right?

Comment: Its possible, but would not be worth doing that much complex. You are better off doing it separately

Comment: Yes, I now think so. Thank You so much,  I appreciate your help :)